# Is there a function to turn the variables of this table into the percentage of each column?

Tags: r, datatable, percentage

I have a table like this:

```
     JUV SUB  AD
  A  137  19  46
  B    0   0  46
  C   16  10   1
  F   23   2   9
  IN  27   9  29
  IS   3   3  25
  M    8   0  27
  R    1   0  66
  S  145  47 189
  T   17   6   9
```

I would like to take a chi square test in order to find a correlation among the groups of the three columns, but in order to do that I need the values divided in the percentage for the three columns.
Prob.table doesn't work because it makes the percentage of the total, not divided for the three groups

Comment: Supposing your dataframe is called `df`, `colMeans(x=df, na.rm = TRUE)`  should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here. Chi Square measures association, not correlation and can be computed only on frequency (count) data, not percentages or proportions. The `chisq.test()` function will handle all of the computations for you. Also the `prop.table` function does exactly what you want (see the manual page `?prop.table` especially the description of the `margin=` argument). When posting, you should use `dput()` to provide your data. That preserves important details of your data - in this case, do you have a data frame or a table. Assuming a data frame:

```
tbl <- structure(list(JUV = c(137L, 0L, 16L, 23L, 27L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 145L, 
17L), SUB = c(19L, 0L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 47L, 6L), AD = c(46L, 
46L, 1L, 9L, 29L, 25L, 27L, 66L, 189L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "F", "IN", "IS", "M", "R", "S", "T"))
```

To get percentages by column, use

```
pct <- prop.table(as.matrix(tbl), 2) * 100
print(addmargins(pct), digits=3)
#         JUV    SUB      AD    Sum
# A    36.340  19.79  10.291  66.42
# B     0.000   0.00  10.291  10.29
# C     4.244  10.42   0.224  14.88
# F     6.101   2.08   2.013  10.20
# IN    7.162   9.38   6.488  23.02
# IS    0.796   3.12   5.593   9.51
# M     2.122   0.00   6.040   8.16
# R     0.265   0.00  14.765  15.03
# S    38.462  48.96  42.282 129.70
# T     4.509   6.25   2.013  12.77
# Sum 100.000 100.00 100.000 300.00
```

For a chi square test:

```
chisq.test(tbl)
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  tbl
# X-squared = 256.14, df = 18, p-value < 2.2e-16
# 
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(tbl) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The warning indicates that some of the expected values are too small.